# Mask RCNN: No module named 'tensorflow.compat.v2'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used Mask RCNN to detect objects on colab.

- Tensorflow == 1.13.1
- Keras == 2.0.8

I have successfully trained the model with the dataset and it got a good results.

But now when I try to run the same code I get the error:

```
No module named 'tensorflow.compat.v2'
```

I have tried many solutions but the code is only compatible with Tensorflow 1.13.1

is there a solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

The `tf.compat.v2` module was added in `1.14`. So you need to upgrade to `1.14`, `1.15`, or `2.0` and this will work fine.

`tensorflow.compat.v2` worked for me on `Tensorflow==1.14`

Try this

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.14
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
```

Comment: yes I have already tried but the problem is not solved

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from:

```
import keras
```

To:

```
import tensorflow.keras
```

**Example to import TimeseriesGenerator from keras**:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
```

Credit to [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘tensorflow.compat.v2‘解决方法](https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_38282306/article/details/117745378)